# Twilio - Error Code 11200 - Webhook on trigger failure to retrieve - Using SMS tutorial

Tags: twilio, sms

Currently building out a VA for a dining booking service.
I previously posted a question asking where to find the messaging service and was pointed out where to go, I've just finished up on the tutorial where it says to copy the webhook URL from the trigger in my flow.

And to copy that into the request URL under the integration for the messaging service setup.
I've then followed the tutorial where it then points me to go to active numbers and select the messaging service as the tester.

However when I then go to text the active number, e.g. 'Hi' or 'Hi there' I receive nothing back, and when I went into the error logs, it stated error code 11200 - A HTTP retrieval failure, with one of the possible causes it states that the webhook url is not leading anywhere, and of course when right click and copy/paste the webhook trigger url, all I get is a message stating:

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

`<Response/>`

So, now I'm at a loss as to why the tutorial doesn't even point out what I'm missing and how I can fix this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Screenshots below show the error at hand according to Twilio console error logs.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit 2:

Here is the tutorial I was following:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/ai-sentiment-analysis-chatbot-whatsapp-sms-openai

The code is exactly what was posted in the tutorial - except in mine I just have extra messages/fetches

Edit 3:

Screenshots of Flow published
[image]

Screenshot of configuration for my Twilio number
[image]

I have set the messaging service / left it untouched and it has no change to the 11200 error.

Screenshot of integration for messaging service
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you don’t see an error in the console of your app or the [Twilio Console](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/debugging-tools)? The later one should give you a detailed error message. Please add that one (text and screensho) to your question. That makes answering your question easier

Comment: I see an error 11200 in the Twilio console under the phone number error logs.
I've edited the main post to show the screenshots.

Comment: @IObert, I thought the issue might so be related to publishing the flow, so I've fixed all configuration errors and published it but the error still persists.

The only thing I haven't tried yet and I'm reluctant to is, under active numbers it states any numbers need to be registered for each number sending sms/mss to the US.

The only option for the UK number I'm using for the SMS is the US.
So does that mean I need to register and pay the costs to get the number to work and allow the trigger to work?

Comment: I don't think this problem is related to the geograpghy of the phone number. I rather believe you return invalid TwiML. Are you intending to return an empty response? If so, try returning `<Response></Response>`. Otherwise, please add your code and the tutorial you try to follow.

Comment: @IObert have edited main post & added the link to the tutorial I was following, the code examples they use is exactly what I have, except for extra send message & reply & open AI functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're missing. Is it possible that you didn't publish the latest version of the Studio flow?

You can find that button on the top-right:
[image: Publish Button]

Comment: No, issue still persists - After I had posted the screenshots in the main post I had already published the flow.

And now the published button is greyed out with the green label stating that the flow is up-to-date.

Comment: I've edited the main post to show state of flow, the configuration of the active number & integration of the messaging service.

The only thing I can think of, is do I need a pro account in order for the SMS to work with an Twilio number?

Answer (score 0):

@IObert

No idea what ended up being the fix, I upgraded my account and then I pressed the speech bubble under the phone numbers in the studio flow section and now it works.

Part of me wants to say it was me upgrading my account but that doesn't make sense, as you should be able to get it working during the trial phase.

only issue I have now is getting openai serverless to work. but will cross that bridge in a bit.

Comment: Great! Probably it was a combination of things!